# Radar Chart Help

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am in need of some assistance for my Radar Chart that I have created.
I have created the Field Set, the Apex Class and the Visualforce Page for this.
What I am having trouble with is, I need to place this Radar Chart on the Account Page Layout but I already have a Controller in my code so I cannot place a StandardController for it to be able to be on the Account. It Errors and says I can only have 1 Controller.
Is there a way to do get this Radar Chart on the Account Layouts.
My code is below;

**APEX Class**

```
public class RadarDemo{

    public RadarDemo() {

    }

    public List<Map<Object,Object>> data = new List<Map<Object,Object>>();
    public String acctId {get;set;}

    public RadarDemo(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        acctId = controller.getRecord().Id ;
    }

    public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getFields() {
        return SObjectType.Account.FieldSets.X7_Ps_Field_Set.getFields();
    }

    public List<Map<Object,Object>> getData() {
        String query = 'SELECT ';
        List<String> fieldNames = new List<String>();

        for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : getFields()){
            query += f.getFieldPath() + ', ';
            fieldNames.add(f.getFieldPath());
        }
        query += 'Id, Name FROM Account where Id=\'' + acctId + '\' LIMIT 1';

        SObject myFieldResults = Database.Query(query);
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult R = myFieldResults.getSObjectType().getDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = R.fields.getmap();

        //creates a map of labels and api names
        Map<String,String> labelNameMap = new Map<String,String>();
        for(String key : fieldMap.keySet()){
             labelNameMap.put(fieldMap.get(key).getDescribe().getName(), fieldMap.get(key).getDescribe().getlabel());
        }

        //creates a map of labels and values
        for(String f : fieldNames){
            String fieldLabel = labelNameMap.get(f);
            String fieldValue = String.valueOf(myFieldResults.get(f));

            Map<Object, Object> m = new Map<Object,Object>();
            m.put('field', fieldLabel);
            m.put('value', fieldValue);
            data.add(m);
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

**Visualforce page**

```
<apex:page controller="RadarDemo">
    <style>
         #vfext4-ext-gen1026 {
        width:800px !important;
         }
    </style>  

        <apex:chart name="myChart" height="600" width="650" legend="false" data="{!data}">
             <apex:legend position="left" />
             <apex:axis type="Radial" position="radial"/>
             <apex:radarSeries title="7 Ps" xField="field" yField="value" tips="true" opacity="0.4"/>
        </apex:chart>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not a point to post demo code, but point is to post code, that give you an error. What do you mean by Account layouts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your first line to

`<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="RadarDemo">`

You will then be able to get your page into the Account Layout, if you look in the `Visualforce` area.